# the lechem hapanim was NOT chametz - where is the source for this?

Tags: beis-hamikdash, chametz-leaven, mincha-meal-offering

We had the discussion what happened with the lechem hapanim on Pessach and the answer is that it was NOT chametz. Where can I read up on this fact?
There were actually only TWO instances of chametz in the Mikdash - 1.shtei ha'lechem on Shavuos and 2.challos of the korban Todah.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/101328/9215

Answer (score 8):

[Second Rashi Pesachim 37a](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14315&st=&pgnum=74&hilite=) quoting Menachos 27a says that they were not allowed to be Chametz.

Thanks to [Rabbi David Lau](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14315&st=&pgnum=74&hilite=) for this answer.

The Gemara Menachos quoted by Rashi as 27a it really [Menachos 57a](https://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=30&daf=57&format=pdf) (last line) and has been corrected in newer Gemaros