# Was the lechem h'apanim baked on pesach?

Tags: passover, maseches-pesachim

Was the lechem h'apanim baked on pesach? If so, was it unleavened during pesach?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/57733/759

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Lechem was anyway not *chameitz*. It was baked on Pesach as it was baked every week.

Mishna [Menachot 5.1](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Menachot.5.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> כל המנחות באות מצה--חוץ מחמץ שבתודה, ושתי הלחם שהן באות חמץ.  רבי מאיר אומר, שאור בודה להן מתוכן ומחמצן.  רבי יהודה אומר, אף היא אינה באה מן המובחר; אלא מביא שאור, ונותן לתוך המידה, וממלא את המידה.  אמרו לו, אף היא הייתה חסרה או יתרה.‏
>
> All grain offerings must be offered unleavened, with the exception of the leavened cakes of the thanksgiving offering and the two loaves [of Shavuot] which are offered leavened.

We learn this from verses as Bartenura explains that Lachme Toda and Shte Halechem are  exceptions.

> כל המנחות באות מצה חוץ מחמץ שבתודה. דכתיב ([ויקרא ז׳:י״ג](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.7.13?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) על חלות לחם חמץ:‏
>
> ושתי הלחם. דכתיב (שם כ״ג) חמץ תאפינה:‏

Note that Korban Toda was not offered from Erev Pesach because of its Chamets component cannot be eaten (Pesachim 11b).  And for this reason some communities don't say Mizmor Letoda in Pesach (Rema OC 51.9).

Comment: Today we assume that all "non-leavened" bread is flat because that's how we bake matzah; but in the Beis HaMikdash they even made big loaves that were baked very quickly and thus not chametz either.

Comment: So if Shavuos fell out on Pesach they wouldn't bake the שתי הלחם. :-)

Comment: I am writing a Shut about שבועות שחל בפסח

Comment: But I think that if Shavuot  is in Pesach, Kohanim have a mitsva to eat them because zmano kavua. @Y  e  z